# Javascript error "Object doesn't support this property or method" displays in DEBUG mode

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, debugging, activexobject

I have a C# .NET windows application that will get HTML files and use them to display data. The HTML files will have javascript in them to help parse/display the data, and one of them uses an activeXObject to display PDF files.

When I install a binary version of the windows application, the PDF file displays properly and is fine.
When I am running from DEBUG mode from VS2008, i get the error:

> Failed to load details page. An
>   exception occurred in the script.
>   Error name: TypeError. Error message:
>   Object doesn't support this property
>   or method

They are both referring to the same HTML page, the only difference is one is a binary install and the other is just my DEBUG build running.

I need to get it working in DEBUG mode so I can test but I'm not sure what's wrong; Any suggestions would definitely be appreciated!

Edit: Sorry here is the HTML Code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>      
<title>Received Fax Preview Page</title>    
</head>     
<body>  
<object data="myfile.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="800" height="600">SUP</object>  
</body>
</html>
```

And i'm just using the C# web browser to display it.

```
 _webBrowser.DocumentText = htmlDoc;
```

Comment: Can you offer a little more information such as the PDF activex you're using and the code the initialises the object?

Comment: Where is the pdf file being accessed from (i.e. where is it stored)? (Oh, and I'm assuming that we're looking at a winforms WebBrowser control, given the fact that you're using the DocumentText property?)

Comment: The pdf was being accessed from the webserver, and yes it was a winforms WebBrowser control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it to work by switching to x86 platform in VS (from Any CPU) and building the project. I'm guessing since my machine is x64, in debug mode the application targets all x64 components and IE x64 can't load PDFs, but maybe in the binary (which is x64) it goes to the common IE x86 bit to open the PDF?

Not 100% sure the explanation, but it is working now.